# Obtaining JSON data with foreach in PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

A site contains monthly data in a JSON format. This can be queried like so:

```
http://www.example.com?startdate=1-1-1985&enddate=31-1-1985
```

I want to be able to run a script that will obtain the specific data I am looking for, starting from today's month, then work backward until null data is returned. Each month's value needs to add up. So far, this is what I've got:

```
//Build base URL:
$userid=$_GET['userid'];
$startdate=/*Beginning of today's month*/;
$enddate=/*End of today's month*/;
$url='http://www.example.com?userid='.$userid.'&startdate='.$startdate.'&enddate='.$enddate;

//Set JSON variables:
$get=file_get_contents($url);
$json=json_decode($get);

//Set loop variables:
$value=0;
$month=0;

/*For each month from today backwards{
    $number=$json->integer;
    if($number!=null){
        $value=$value+$number;
        $month=$month+1;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}
echo $value;
echo $month;
*/
```

The part I'm having problems with is the beginning of the fourth part. How do I run a loop that starts with the range of today's month, obtain $number, then repeat with the previous month, until it reaches a month that returns null?

Comment: `mktime()` is pretty useful in these situations, as it allows you to simply -1 on the month, and it figures out the year changes and days and such. Also `strtotime("now -$m month")` if you like dealing with more 'readable' date changes hehehe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `DateTime` object and it's associated methods ( specifically `sub` in this case ) to count backwards by subtracting 1month at a time. An array stores the months/dates and the url is constructed using the variable counter `$i`

Initially this has a maximum backwards range of 20years ( which I guessed would be more than enough ) but it's easy to change.

```
$df='Y-m-d';
$userid=$_GET['userid'];

$timezone=new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$interval=new DateInterval('P1M');

$ts=date( $df, strtotime( date('Y-m-1') ) );
$tf=date( $df, strtotime( date('Y-m-1'). ' - 20 years') );

$start=new DateTime( $ts, $timezone );
$end=new DateTime( $tf, $timezone );

$dates=array();
$i=0;

while( $start->sub( $interval ) > $end ){
    $dates[]=$start->format( $df );
    if( $i > 1 ){

        $startdate=$dates[ $i - 1 ];
        $enddate=$dates[ $i ];
        $url='http://www.example.com?userid='.$userid.'&startdate='.$startdate.'&enddate='.$enddate;
        echo $url,'<br />';

        /* uncomment when happy with mechanism */
        /*

        $data=file_get_contents( $url );
        if( $data ) ) {
            $json=json_decode( $data );
            #process.....
            break;
        }
        */
    }
    $i++;
}
```

A snippet of the output

```
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-10-01&enddate=2017-09-01
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-09-01&enddate=2017-08-01
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-08-01&enddate=2017-07-01
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-07-01&enddate=2017-06-01
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-06-01&enddate=2017-05-01
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-05-01&enddate=2017-04-01
http://www.example.com?userid=bobodaclown&startdate=2017-04-01&enddate=2017-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

By using strtotime() and mktime() functions you can while loop until you get Null results. The below code will print 5 urls for 5 months. Change while condition accordingly.

```
// define $i
$i=0;
$userid = '343';//$_GET['userid'];  //dont forget to replace with userid
do{
    $timestring =  strtotime("now -$i month");
    //get Month
    $month = date('m',$timestring);
    //get Year
    $year = date('Y',$timestring);
    // First date Month and Year
    $startdate = date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
    // Last date Month and Year
    $enddate = date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month+1, 0,$year));

    $url='http://www.example.com?userid='.$userid.'&startdate='.$startdate.'&enddate='.$enddate;
    // commenting your code 
    //Set JSON variables:
    //$get=file_get_contents($url);
    //$json=json_decode($get);
    // $number=$json->integer;
    echo $url;
    echo "\n";
    $i++;
}while ($i!=5); // change while condition according to your requirement. while ($number!=null)
```

Out Put:

```
http://www.example.com?userid=343&startdate=01-12-2017&enddate=31-12-2017
http://www.example.com?userid=343&startdate=01-11-2017&enddate=30-11-2017
http://www.example.com?userid=343&startdate=01-10-2017&enddate=31-10-2017
http://www.example.com?userid=343&startdate=01-09-2017&enddate=30-09-2017
http://www.example.com?userid=343&startdate=01-08-2017&enddate=31-08-2017
```